# UItableview accessory

Tags: iphone

hi
I want to know, is it possible to change the color of UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator? if yes then how is it possible..

In my app the background color of UITableView and disclosure indicator have same color.. so it not visible.. but when we click the cell it visible..

please help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an image like UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator , inside your

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {}
```